# Load meta box inside meta box.. is this possible?

Tags: metabox

Wondering if I might do this as I'm looking to create a To Do View like on github project view does.

Any insight will be appreciated, I may just go for a completely custom solution but if someone knows if there is a way to do this without being hackish I'm all ears, or eyes.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would having a meta box inside a meta box achieve a to do view?

Comment: Well you may be right.  I have been thinking about this issue for sometime since this post yesterday.  Just going to do a meta box with the columns Listing Task by current status.  The tasks are too in depth to be able to moved around anyhow as they may contain a wealth of information from Bill of Materials to detailed construction site descriptions.  Thanks for replying.